# How can you register a text to markups by program?

Tags: autodesk-forge

```
const config = { extensions: ["Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore", "Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui"] }
this.viewer = new this.$Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv, config)
```

I'm using MarkupsGui.
What I want do to is

- put text in EditMode
- take a screenshot by clicking a screenshot button

However, when I take a screenshot right after I put a text box, the text is not show in a picture. The text is not registered yet to markups.

If I click somewhere on the forge screen after I put a text, and take a screenshot, the text is shown in the picture.

How can you register a text to markups by program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog post that goes through the process here:  https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/screenshot-markups

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, it doesn't help. This issue only happens with text box. The blog post you suggested doesn't say about it.

Comment: yes, you have to exit text edit mode, for it to save the state, before taking the screenshot.  I'm sorry I didn't pick up on the details of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.
If you change edit mode from text mode to any other mode, the text is registered as a markup and shown up in a screenshot.

```
markupExt.changeEditMode(new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EditModePolycloud(markupExt))
```

*EditModePolycloud is random. You can choose any mode except text mode.